# Jasper reports: Error executing SQL statement for :

Tags: jasper-reports

The following is the error i got while compiling the jrxml file.

```
Error filling print... 
Error executing SQL statement for : Activity_Summary_Report 
Setting up the file resolver...
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : Activity_Summa ry_Report
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:240)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1086)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:667       )
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:89    1)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)    
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
Caused by: commicrosoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:233)
... 12 more  
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

The parameter I am taking in jrxml file and query strings are

```
<parameter name="EndDate" isForPrompting="true" class="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression ><![CDATA[new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString><![CDATA[declare @startdate as datetime;
declare @enddate as datetime;
declare @sitegroup as nvarchar(50);
set @startdate = $P{EndDate}-1;
set @enddate = $P{EndDate};
set @sitegroup = 'BBXNCR';
set NOCOUNT ON; -- Added by JC230090: Fixes bug when running query with Jasper

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo]. [#temp_invlines]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[#temp_invlines]
create table #temp_invlines (site_iid uniqueidentifier, invoice_line_type_iid int,   sub_total float, tax_total float,line_total float, product_type_iid int);
insert into #temp_invlines (site_iid,invoice_line_type_iid, sub_total, tax_total,   line_total, product_type_iid)
select h.site_iid, invoice_line_type_iid, l.sub_total, l.tax_total, l.line_total, l.product_type_iid
from invoice_lines l
    inner join invoices h on l.invoice_iid = h.invoice_iid
where h.invoice_dt >= @startdate and h.invoice_dt < @enddate

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[#temp_payment_invoices]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[#temp_payment_invoices]
create table #temp_payment_invoices (site_iid uniqueidentifier, inv_amount float);
insert into #temp_payment_invoices (site_iid, inv_amount)
select i.site_iid, i.total
from invoice_payments p
    inner join Invoice_Payment_Invoice_Xref pXref on p.invoice_payment_iid = pXref.invoice_payment_iid
    inner join invoices i on pXref.invoice_iid = i.invoice_iid
where p.payment_dt >= @startdate and p.payment_dt < @enddate

 IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[#temp_promocodes]') AND type in (N'U'))
 DROP TABLE [dbo].[#temp_promocodes]
 create table #temp_promocodes (site_iid uniqueidentifier, invoice_promo_line_type_iid int, promo_amount float);
 insert into #temp_promocodes (site_iid, invoice_promo_line_type_iid, promo_amount)
select h.site_iid, pl.invoice_promo_line_type_iid, pl.amount
from invoice_promo_lines pl
inner join invoices h on pl.invoice_iid = h.invoice_iid
where h.invoice_dt >= @startdate and h.invoice_dt < @enddate



select 
rtrim(s.site_id) as [Site ID]
, rtrim(ss.Description) as [Status]
, @startdate as [Date]
, datename(dw,@startdate) as [DoW]
, rtrim(s.name) as [Store Code]
, rtrim(isnull(sg.Description,'')) as [Site Group]
, rtrim(s.address1) + ', ' + rtrim(s.city) + ', ' + rtrim(s.state) + ' ' + rtrim(s.Zip)    as [Address]
, rtrim(pg.description) as [RentPriceGroup]

, (select count(*) from invoices h where h.invoice_dt >= @startdate and h.invoice_dt < @enddate and h.site_iid = s.site_iid) as [Trans]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 1) as [Rent Rev]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 2) as [Ext Day Rev]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 0 and l.product_type_iid = 2) as [Used Sell Rev]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 0 and l.product_type_iid <> 2) as [New Sell Rev]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid) as [Rev Total]
, (select isnull(sum(tax_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid) as [Tax Total]
, (select isnull(sum(line_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid) as [Grand Total]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid)    /
(select case when count(*) = 0 then 1 else count(*) end from invoices h where h.invoice_dt >= @startdate and h.invoice_dt < @enddate and h.site_iid = s.site_iid)
as [Rev/Trans]
, (select isnull(count(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 1) as [Rent Cnt]
, (select isnull(count(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 2) as [Ext Day Cnt]
, (select isnull(count(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 0 and l.product_type_iid = 2) as [Used Sell Cnt]
, (select isnull(count(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 0 and l.product_type_iid <> 2) as [New Sell Cnt]
, (select isnull(count(promo_amount),0) from #temp_promocodes p where p.site_iid = s.site_iid and p.invoice_promo_line_type_iid = 0) as [CustSrv Promo Cnt]
, (select isnull(sum(promo_amount),0) from #temp_promocodes p where p.site_iid = s.site_iid and p.invoice_promo_line_type_iid = 0) as [CustSrv Promo Amt]
, (select isnull(count(promo_amount),0) from #temp_promocodes p where p.site_iid = s.site_iid and p.invoice_promo_line_type_iid = 1) as [Marketing Promo Cnt]
, (select isnull(sum(promo_amount),0) from #temp_promocodes p where p.site_iid = s.site_iid and p.invoice_promo_line_type_iid = 1) as [Marketing Promo Amt]

, (SELECT  
    isnull(count(*),0)
FROM Invoice_Lines ilrtn 
    INNER JOIN Invoices ihrtn on ilrtn.invoice_iid = ihrtn.invoice_iid 
    inner join customer_ids c on ihrtn.customer_id_iid = c.customer_id_iid
    INNER JOIN Invoices ihrent on ihrtn.customer_id_iid = ihrent.customer_id_iid  
    INNER JOIN Invoice_lines ilrent on ihrent.invoice_iid = ilrent.invoice_iid 
WHERE ihrtn.invoice_dt >= @startdate
    and ihrtn.invoice_dt < @enddate
    and ilrtn.invoice_line_type_iid in (0,2)
    AND ihrent.invoice_dt <= ihrtn.invoice_dt 
    AND ilrent.invoice_line_type_iid in (1) 
    AND ilrent.piece_id = ilrtn.piece_id 
    and ihrtn.site_iid = s.site_iid 
) as [Invoices]

, (SELECT  
    isnull(sum(ilrent.line_total + ilrtn.line_total),0)
FROM Invoice_Lines ilrtn 
    INNER JOIN Invoices ihrtn on ilrtn.invoice_iid = ihrtn.invoice_iid 
    inner join customer_ids c on ihrtn.customer_id_iid = c.customer_id_iid
    INNER JOIN Invoices ihrent on ihrtn.customer_id_iid = ihrent.customer_id_iid  
    INNER JOIN Invoice_lines ilrent on ihrent.invoice_iid = ilrent.invoice_iid 
WHERE ihrtn.invoice_dt >= @startdate
    and ihrtn.invoice_dt < @enddate
    and ilrtn.invoice_line_type_iid in (0,2)
    AND ihrent.invoice_dt <= ihrtn.invoice_dt 
    AND ilrent.invoice_line_type_iid in (1) 
    AND ilrent.piece_id = ilrtn.piece_id 
    and ihrtn.site_iid = s.site_iid 
) as [Collectable]


, ( select isnull(sum(p.amount),0)
from invoice_payments p
where p.payment_dt >= @startdate and p.payment_dt < @enddate
and p.invoice_payment_iid in (
    select distinct p.invoice_payment_iid
    from invoice_payments p
    inner join Invoice_Payment_Invoice_Xref pXref on p.invoice_payment_iid = pXref.invoice_payment_iid
    inner join invoices i on pXref.invoice_iid = i.invoice_iid
    where p.payment_dt >= @startdate and p.payment_dt < @enddate
    and i.site_iid = s.site_iid
    group by p.invoice_payment_iid, pXref.invoice_iid)
) as [Payments Collected]
from sites s
inner join Site_Statuses_Enum ss on s.site_status_iid = ss.site_status_iid
inner join Site_Rent_Price_Groups as pg on s.site_rent_price_group_iid =     pg.site_rent_price_group_iid
left outer join Site_SiteGroup_XRef sgx on s.site_iid = sgx.site_iid
left outer join Site_Groups sg on sgx.site_group_iid = sg.site_group_iid
where sg.Description in (@sitegroup) or sg.Description is null
order by s.site_id

drop table #temp_promocodes
drop table #temp_payment_invoices
drop table #temp_invlines;]]></queryString>
```

Please help me how to resolve it. When I am executing the same query directly in Sql server management studio, this is executing fine. But through jasper reports, it is throwing exception. Please Help me..

Comment: Have you copied the JDBC drivers for connecting to your MS SQL Server database to Jasper's folders? Have you set up a connection in iReport and Jasper Server for this?

Comment: yes @Rachcha I have copied "sqlserverjdbc.jar" file. And I have created MS SQL Server connection in Ireport 3.0.0 as well as set up jasper server 3.0.0 for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue got resolved. It was because of the input parameters ($P{StartDate},$P{EndDate}) are of data type `date` not `datetime`. Because the date data type's precision only runs to day level, not anything smaller.

If you ensure that the parameters supplied by your application (below) are of type datetime and not date, you should get rid of the error.

```
$P{StartDate}
$P{EndDate}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are **sure about your connection and have tested it successfully before**, I'd recommend you **remove all the Transact-SQL code** from your query in Jasper.

Jasper does not allow anything apart from a `SELECT` query inside a report JRXML. You must only use `SELECT` statement and nothing else - not even `SET` or `DECLARE`. Jasper is just a reporting engine, not a database client. No DDL and DML allowed.

Modify your code and make it into a single `SELECT` query.

Comment: In another jrxml file, I do have some declare statements. Still that file is generating report. But I could not with this file only.

Comment: Remove the `CREATE`, `DROP`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements.

Comment: But I got empty report while on the same SQL connection with no data in tables. After I inserted data into tables, I am getting this exception.

Comment: Check with your data and return fields. There can be a data type mismatch also.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

for similar kind of issue